# Merging video and Audio using FFmpegKit in Flutter

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg

I'm trying to merge video with audio using FFmpegKit.

I have given the command,
String command =
"-y -i ${file.path} -i ${result!.files.single.path} -map 0:v:0  -map 1:a:0 -c:v copy "
"-shortest ${appDirectory!.path}/output.mp4";
and it is working on only a specific mp3 available in my local. I don't know why it is not working with the other audios/mp3 files.
It would be a great assistance if you could.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just find out the solution. The problem was whenever file.path contains any space then it was throwing the error so I just copied the current file and stored in another file by replacing its path name(and deleted the previous file).